# GCP unable to ssh from the browser

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I recently added a firewall rule to my instance, so that it can be accessed only from whitelisted IPs.

After creating this firewall I am unable to ssh using the browser window option. The CLI works fine which is weird. I am able to login using CLI.

I am getting the following error only on browser login.

```
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser login is coming through GCP, from a different IP address. Check your server logs to see which IP address is being denied, and add it to the allow list.

Comment: I checked the logs. The IP address differs each time. Is there any way I could get a range of allowed internal IP addresses or have a constant IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Known issues](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#known_issues) of **SSH from the browser** to check if there is a match with the issue you are facing.